# Issue with setVectorGraphics method in Imagick?

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagick

I'm working on a task which requires parsing SVG path data for use as a clip mask in Imagick... right now, I'm getting errors trying to use the setVectorGraphics method- the following code produces an error message like:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to draw image'

```
$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor("red");
$draw->circle(20, 20, 50, 50);
$draw->setFillColor("blue");
$draw->circle(50, 70, 50, 50);
$draw->rectangle(50, 120, 80, 150);
//Get the drawing as a string
$SVG = $draw->getVectorGraphics();

$draw2 = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw2->setVectorGraphics($SVG);
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->newImage(200, 200, 'white');
$imagick->setImageFormat("png");
$imagick->drawImage($draw2);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

(code comes from [this demo](https://github.com/Danack/Imagick-demos/blob/master/src/ImagickDemo/ImagickDraw/functions.php#L1606))

I'm pretty sure the usage of Imagick and ImagickDraw here is correct... is this a bug in the Imagick library? If so, is there some way to work around the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the library call to ImageMagick is just not working, which is why that example isn't viewable on http://phpimagick.com/ImagickDraw as it just doesn't work. Someone needs to report the issue upstream at http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=3 which may involve writing an example in C, which is why it's on my list of things to do, rather than list of things done.

Comment: @Danack no worries - the solution presented below is an acceptable workaround. Thanks for the excellent library and tutorials!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure the usage of Imagick and ImagickDraw here is correct

Correct. PHP's implementation of ImageMagick's C-API, in this instance, is complete.

> ... is this a bug in the Imagick library?

Yes. This feature has a history of issues, and behavior has changed across ImageMagick version. Ensure you have the latest version, author a test case, and submit a bug report.

> If so, is there some way to work around the issue?

The `ImagickDraw::getVectorGraphics` returns a string of xml nodes, but not a complete XML document. Your calling code needs to generate the missing parent node.

```php
$SVG = $draw->getVectorGraphics();
// ....
$draw2->setVectorGraphics('<root>' . $SVG . '</root>');
```

Comment: Awesome - this solution worked perfectly. I did look at the SVG output of getVectorGraphics, but am not familiar enough with the format to have spotted the missing tags. Many thanks for your help! Apologies though, I apparently lack the reputation points needed to upvote :P

Comment: @TarekSami Glad to help. Simply "accept" this answer to help gain reputation points.

Comment: @emcconville You appear to know a bit about Imagick and it's bugs. Could you open other issues you would like fixed at https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/ please ? e.g. I only found out about this problem with setVectorGraphics recently - https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues/82